# Почему не делается дамп базы через консоль?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Пишу в десктопной консоле mysql

```
mysqldump -uadmin -p9047scw mysql > mysqldump.sql;
```

выдает :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump -uadmin -p9047scw users > mysqldump.sql'
>   at line 1

Вроде все по синтаксису

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [database] > [dump_name.sql]
```

Не пойму что не так?)

Comment: А что из себя представляет ваша десктопная консоль?

Comment: @MaxRaskolnikov это старинный вопрос, я тогда пытался запустить из нативный консоли mysql, вместо ssh.
ниже там скрины этой консоли есть

Comment: Имеете в виду phpMyAdmin?

Comment: нет, консоль mysql , которая доступна после установки workbranch в win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqldump` это консольная команда, вы пытаетесь выполнить ее в качестве SQL запроса, это не правильно

Comment: да вроде я и использую её как консольную команду в mysql command line ? https://yadi.sk/i/iyh49MHsuXyEk

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко в том и дело, что ее нужно выполнять оттуда же, откуда вы вызываеть mysql

Comment: @Etki в файле php чтоли?)

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко нет, из консоли

Comment: причем тут php? не входи в клиент mysql и выполни команду в консоли. Угадай, для чего люди пользуются mysql клиентом? Правильно, чтобы исполнить там SQL код, так вот дамп базы делается не из под клиента. Открой консоль и выполни `mysqldump`

Comment: Вообщем я разобрался, просто пользоваться отдельными клиентам mysql и отдельным php, apach не айс, через консоль кстати также не работает команда без определенных манипуляций, надо прописывать путь к бинарнику в окружении. на хостинге через ssh все отлично работает, тема закрыта)